# Code blocks error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, codeblocks

Can anybody please provide me any suggestions why the compiler shows the following error:

> expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant.

Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  ifstream f("bac.in");
  long x,okp=0,oki=0,k=0, p=2,c=9999997;
  while(f>>x) {
    k++;
    if((x%==0) && (x>=p)) {
      okp++; 
      p=x;
    }
    else
      if((x%2==1) && (x<=c)) {
        oki++; 
        c=x;
      }
  }
  if((okp+oki)==k) 
    cout<<"yes"; 
  else 
    cout<<"no";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Surely the compiler tells you where (line number) it's expected. Look there.

Answer (score 1):

Change `(x%==0)` to `(x%2==0)` on line 10.